# Basic HTTP Parsing Using Twisted

Tags: python, http, logging, twisted, twisted.web

I am a newcomer to the Python and Twisted game so excuse the ignorance I will likely be asking this question with. As a sort of first program, I am trying to write a basic HTTP server using twisted.web.sever which would simply print to screen the HTTP request, and then print to screen the HTTP response. I am trying to print the entire message. Here is what I have so far:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
import time

class TestPage(Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    def render_GET(self, request):
        response = "Success"
        print "You're request was %s" % request
        print "The sever's response was %s" % response
        return response

resource = TestPage()
factory = Site(resource)
reactor.listenTCP(8000, factory)
reactor.run()
```

So far, I am having success printing the request. What I want to know is where I can access the raw response data, not just the textual message. Also, if I wanted to start parsing the request/response for information, what would be the best way to go about doing that?

Edit: I'm also new to stackoverflow, how do I get this code to display properly?

Comment: Highlight your code and click the one-zero-one-zero code icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Request](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.server.Request.html) and [IRequest](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.iweb.IRequest.html) API docs to get an idea of what that `request` parameter offers you.  You should be able to find just about everything in the request there.

I'm not sure what you mean by *raw response data* though.  The response is up to you to generate.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the IRequest API. That had exactly what I was looking for. To clarify my previous question, I guess what I really want is the Request object representing the response from the server. 

Looking at your answer though, I think I may be confused. My understanding of the framework was that I just write up some generic HTTP response, then twisted goes ahead and adds all the header information later, am I supposed to be adding that header information? If I'm supposed to add it, where is a good place to look for demos on how to do that?

Comment: themaestro: Take a look at this: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/api/twisted.web.server.Request.html  You can add headers, set the response code, etc. And here's a set of tutorials you can look at to get started: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/index.html